`reduce` in purrr with `+` but ignore missing value in R
How can I use reduce function together with lag to obtain the summation but at the same time ignore missing values?
a <- data.frame( b = c(1, 2, NA, 3, 4, 5))
a %>% mutate(addition = reduce(map(0:1, ~lag(b, .x)) , `+`))

The resulting table



b
addition




1
NA


2
3


NA
NA


3
NA


4
7


5
9



My desire result is



b
addition




1
1


2
3


NA
2


3
3


4
7


5
9



Thus, the desire result is to ignore the NA and do the addition for the current value and its lag values. I simplified the example but in the actual case, I need the rolling sum of 12.
I have tried the following, and the results are the same for the column addition in which it returns 25 for all rows. Why does this not work?
a <- data.frame( b = c(1, 2, NA, 3, 4, 5))
a %>% mutate(addition = reduce(map(0:1, ~lag(b, .x)) , ~sum(.x, .y, na.rm = TRUE)))


If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, cumsum() with na.rm=TRUE should do the trick, instead of using reduce and sum.

I am not sure if reduce is the right function for such calculation. Here are couple of options to achieve the same result.

Replace NA values with 0 and add using +

library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

a %>% mutate(addition = replace(b, is.na(b),0) + replace(lag(b), is.na(lag(b)),0))

#   b addition
#1  1        1
#2  2        3
#3 NA        2
#4  3        3
#5  4        7
#6  5        9


Use map2 and sum the two values ignoring NA values.

a %>% mutate(addition = map2(b, lag(b), ~sum(.x, .y, na.rm = TRUE)))

EDIT
Based on your update if you need to do rolling operations then use rolling functions. For eg - with zoo::rollapplyr
a %>% 
   mutate(addition = zoo::rollapplyr(b, 2, \(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE),
                      fill = first(b)))

#   b addition
#1  1        1
#2  2        3
#3 NA        2
#4  3        3
#5  4        7
#6  5        9


Following your approach/thought process you can make sum work by using rowwise
library(dplyr)

a %>% 
  mutate(addition = lag(b)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(addition = sum(b, addition, na.rm=T))
# A tibble: 6 × 2
# Rowwise:
      b addition
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1        1
2     2        3
3    NA        2
4     3        3
5     4        7
6     5        9


a$addition <- convolve(
  c(0, 
    ifelse(is.na(a$b), 0, a$b)), 
  c(1, 1), 
  type = "filter")

#   b addition
#1  1        1
#2  2        3
#3 NA        2
#4  3        3
#5  4        7
#6  5        9

